# YouTube' object has no attribute 'video'

Tags: python, python-import, youtube

Obtengo este error: `'YouTube' object has no attribute 'video'` y no tengo ni idea de por que no va.

```
import pytube

stream = pytube.YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZSpHIBxReY").video.streams.filter(subtype='mp4').first()

stream.download(filename= "money")
```

Simplemente esto:
`stream = pytube.YouTube(url)` ya genera ese error

Comment: Siempre que puedo le recuerdo a los usuarios que *descargar* videos de *Youtube* es una infracción a sus términos de uso. La empresa *Youtube* está en todo el derecho de demandar por este motivo. Siempre debes tener esto en cuenta. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Hola! buscando un poco por la red encontré un par de preguntas con problemas relacionados al tuyo...

Para empezar [aquí esta la documentación del modulo que quieres importar](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/python-pytube/latest/python-pytube.pdf) para que le eches un vistazo rápido.

Aparentemente tu error puede surgir por dos causas (según lo que leí).

## 1.- Desactualizado

La solución que marcan [aqui](https://steakrecords.com/es/714944-pytube-module-error-python-error-handling-pytube.html) es desinstalar el modulo y volver a instalar.

Para desinstalar:

```
pip uninstall pytube
```

Para instalar nuevamente:

```
$ python -m pip install pytube
```

O para instalar desde github(muchísimo mas recomendable):

```
$ python -m pip install git+https://github.com/nficano/pytube
```

## 2.- No instalado

Para verificar que esta instalado:

```
pip list | grep PyTube
```

Y debe regresar:

> PyTube (0.1)

Todo esto lo saque de estas paginas: [Esta de aquí](https://pypi.org/project/pytube/) y [esta de acá](https://steakrecords.com/es/714944-pytube-module-error-python-error-handling-pytube.html)

Espero la información te sea de ayuda.

Buen día.

Comment: nada de eso funciono , tengo la version mas reciente

Comment: Si, estoy viendo que el problema esta en que no se encuentra el atributo `videos` ¿has probado quitando el atributo y ver que sucede?

Comment: vaya el problema era ese atributo.... pues hace una semana me funcionaba asi.. xd

Comment: Como quiera pasa a leer el primer enlace:) estuve haciendo diversas pruebas y me arrojaba que no existían atributos que se supone que si jsdhiusadhskjfd que bueno que fui de ayuda:)

Comment: Siempre que puedo le recuerdo a los usuarios que descargar videos de Youtube es una infracción a sus términos de uso. La empresa Youtube está en todo el derecho de demandar por este motivo. Siempre debes tener esto en cuenta. Saludos